# Loops Infinity of a spectrum

Tags: model-categories, stable-homotopy-theory, spectra

Let $\mathbf{X}$ be an (orthogonal) spectrum (can assume that it's an $\Omega$-spectrum if this helps give a positive answer) and give the category of orthogonal spectra the stable model structure.

Let $\Omega^\infty$ be the total right derived functor of evaluation at $0$.

I want to show that
$$
\Omega^\infty (S^n \wedge \mathbf{X}) \simeq \mathbf{X}(\Bbb{R}^n).
$$

---

**Attempt:**

Since we can assume that $\mathbf{X}$ is an $\Omega$-spectrum, (hence fibrant in the stable model structure) $\Omega^\infty$ is simply just evaluation at $0$. So the left-hand side becomes 
$$
S^n \wedge \mathbf{X}(0).
$$

This comes with an obvious structure map to $\mathbf{X}(\Bbb{R}^n)$, but this map, in general, is not a weak homotopy equivalence.

Comment: I  believe that $(S^n\wedge X)_0=(\mathfrak{L}(0,\mathbb{R}^n)\wedge X)_0=\mathfrak{L}(0,\mathbb{R}^n)\wedge X_0=(\mathfrak{L}(0,-)\wedge X_0)_n\cong X_n$, since the last evaluation map is a component of a natural isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify the isomorphism?

Comment: It is Lemma 4.9 in *Equivariant Orthogonal Spectra and S-Modules* by Mandell and May.

Comment: Thanks. One last question, how do we get the zero case from the coend?

Comment: Ok, my original argument for that seems less obvious than I thought. How about this, $\Omega^\infty(S^n\wedge X)\cong Map_*(S^0,\Omega^\infty(S^n\wedge X))\cong Sp(S^0,S^n\wedge X)\cong Sp(S^n\wedge S^{-n},S^n\wedge X)\cong Sp(S^{-n},\Omega^n(S^n\wedge X))\simeq Sp(S^{-n},X)\simeq X_n$, where I have used Lemma 3.8 of that book.

Comment: I assume when you say $S^{n}$ you mean the shifted suspension spectrum? And how is a map of spectra from the $(-n)$ suspension spectrum to $X$ equivalent to $X_n$?

Comment: Yes, I'm identifying $S^n$ with $\Sigma^n S^n\cong \mathbb{S}\wedge S^n$. $S^{-n}$ is defined to be the spectrum $(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ (in Mandell-May's notation this is definition 4.6 and notation 4.7) so the last isomorphism is Yoneda.